# Long running jobs don't restart after Sidekiq reload

Tags: sidekiq

I have some data processing which take days running in 10 Sidekiq workers. For some reason (probably short of memory) Sidekiq stops then monit restarts it. The issue I have is that the jobs don't restart. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq is being shut down incorrectly.  If you `kill -9` sidekiq, you lose the jobs being processed.

Comment: Thanks Mike, actually monit reports high memory usage just before sidekiq  stops. Can that be a cause for sidekiq to stop? I don't `kill -9` it.

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#my-sidekiq-process-is-disappearing